# Sum negative row values with previous rows pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble finding a good way to find all negative entries in a column and move them up the column, summing them up with the existing entry (i.e. subtracting the negative entry from the present entry) until all values are positive.

It is important that there are no negative values for the final dataframe & that all previously negative entries = 0. Also, the table is repeating, which means that I need to aggregate the results both based on the ID as well as on the entries (only do summations of entries of the same ID).

Based on an already presented table here:

Present:

| ID | Date | Entries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013 | 100 |
| 1 | 2014 | 0 |
| 1 | 2015 | 60 |
| 1 | 2016 | -30 |
| 1 | 2017 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018 | 50 |
| 1 | 2019 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020 | -20 |
| 2 | 2013 | 100 |
| 2 | 2014 | 0 |
| 2 | 2015 | 60 |
| 2 | 2016 | -30 |
| 2 | 2017 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018 | 50 |
| 2 | 2019 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | -20 |

Desired:

| ID | Date | Entries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013 | 100 |
| 1 | 2014 | 0 |
| 1 | 2015 | 30 |
| 1 | 2016 | 0 |
| 1 | 2017 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018 | 30 |
| 1 | 2019 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020 | 0 |
| 2 | 2013 | 100 |
| 2 | 2014 | 0 |
| 2 | 2015 | 30 |
| 2 | 2016 | 0 |
| 2 | 2017 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018 | 30 |
| 2 | 2019 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | 0 |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try reverse cumsum after creating a group, then mask:

```
s = df['Entries'].gt(0).cumsum()
u= df['Entries'][::-1].groupby(s).cumsum().mask(df['Entries'].le(0),0)
out = df.assign(New_Entries=u) # you can assign to the original column too.
```

---

```
print(out)
    ID  Date  Entries  New_Entries
0    1  2013      100          100
1    1  2014        0            0
2    1  2015       60           30
3    1  2016      -30            0
4    1  2017        0            0
5    1  2018       50           30
6    1  2019        0            0
7    1  2020      -20            0
8    2  2013      100          100
9    2  2014        0            0
10   2  2015       60           30
11   2  2016      -30            0
12   2  2017        0            0
13   2  2018       50           30
14   2  2019        0            0
15   2  2020      -20            0
```

Comment: shame that cumsum doesn't have an ascending argument but this is pretty sweet, nice one.

Comment: @Manakin I looked up twice to make sure it didnt existed since I assumed it would be there somewhere. Good thing is pandas retains index so i didn't have to reverse the series before assigning. :)

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward recursive function on the array of values

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID  Date    Entries
1   2013    100
1   2014    0
1   2015    60
1   2016    -30
1   2017    0
1   2018    50
1   2019    0
1   2020    -20
2   2013    100
2   2014    0
2   2015    60
2   2016    -30
2   2017    0
2   2018    50
2   2019    0
2   2020    -20"""), sep="\t")

def shiftminus(a):
    touch=False
    for i,n in enumerate(a):
        if n<0 and i>0:
            a[i-1] += a[i]
            a[i] = 0
            touch=True
    if touch:
        a = shiftminus(a)
    return a

df["Entries"] = shiftminus(df["Entries"].values)
```

### output

```
 ID  Date  Entries
  1  2013      100
  1  2014        0
  1  2015       30
  1  2016        0
  1  2017        0
  1  2018       30
  1  2019        0
  1  2020        0
  2  2013      100
  2  2014        0
  2  2015       30
  2  2016        0
  2  2017        0
  2  2018       30
  2  2019        0
  2  2020        0
```